# Ruby Array of Instances, modifying attributes

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm attempting to write a sudoku solver in ruby and I've run into an issue. Consider the following code:

`@grid = Array.new(9,Array.new(9,Cell.new))`

where `Cell` is defined as:

```
class Cell
    def initialize
        @value = 0
        @possibles = Array (1..9)
    end

    attr_accessor :value, :possibles
end
```

When I initialize my 9x9 `@grid` 2D array, it prints out the values

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

which is what I expect. However, when I try running something like `@grid[5][5].value = 7` then the `@grid` prints out the values

```
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

I realize that my 9x9 `@grid` 2D array is full of the *same* instance of `Cell`

What is the syntax to create a 2D array of *unique* instances so that I can manipulate them individually?

Comment: Also look at matrix  http://dpaste.com/36FVG6F

Comment: Further to @JLB's suggestion, the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) and [Vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) classes have several methods that would be convenient here, including ones for stabbing out columns and 3x3 submatrices. Note that an easy way to see if a 3x3 submatrix `m` contains any duplicates is to test `arr = m.to_a.flatten; arr == arr.uniq`. A similar approach could be taken for rows and columns, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a block

```
@grid = Array.new(9) { Array.new(9) { Cell.new } }
```

Comment: dpears, If you leave a comment on a question or answer the author of the comment/question will be notified by SO. It is only when you leave a comment for someone else that you need to include @username in the comment for that person to be notified of the comment.

Comment: Also, don't use comments to say "thanks". The comment-box specifically mentions that. They only clog the system.